# storing data into array from the url in android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to the android. I want to store the a the data from the web  link..
I will give you the link..which have only one value.

"https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/305276/fields/1/24?api_key=KD5IR14FQW33TM4Y"

I want to assign the value coming from the link to a variable in my android program..i am trying but i didn't get..please help me..

This is the code actually i tried..

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class urll {
public static String data(int i) {
    URL oracle = null;
    String a = null; 

    try {
        oracle = new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/305276/fields/1/24?api_key=KD5IR14FQW33TM4Y");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection yc = null;
    try {
        yc = oracle.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String inputLine;
    try {
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            a=inputLine;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //      System.out.println(inputLine);
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      return a;
   }

 }
```

Comment: The data coming in API is "0". You need to get that value?

Comment: there is no array in reponse only 0

Comment: yes that single value to a integer variable.

Comment: You may need to add `oracle.setRequestMethod("GET");` and `oracle.connect();` after `oracle.openConnection();` (after casting to `HttpURLConnection`)